# Is it possible to addClass, removeClass based on aria-hidden values?

Tags: jquery, attributes, accessibility

Sorry if my question is too silly or non-relative, but I'm so so newbie in jquery... Anyway, I'm trying to add some background letters (with :before pseudo element) on parent div of slideshow based on aria-hidden values...

This is for an hosted cms (kind of DIY website builder) and I don't have access to the html but only to the head section of the site. Thus in the parent div I have some content (heading, text, button) on the left side and pre-installed slideshow on the right side  - the slideshow has regular structure of ul and li's, however there is no any "active" class on the visible slide - the only change I detect is that all the li's have aria-hidden="true" and the visible one(the active) changes to aria-hidden="false", so I must hang on this... to add my :before pseudo element on the parent.

CSS

```
        .brandName:before{
                content: 'BRAND NAME';
                color: #d2dbdc;
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
                -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
                -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
                opacity: 0.6;
                font-family: "Lato",sans-serif,"google";
                font-weight: 700;
                letter-spacing: 5vw;
                font-size: 7vw;
                z-index: -1;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div class="landing-section">

  <div class="left-side">
    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <button>Some Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="right-side">
    <div id="cc-m-gallery-7739661064" class="cc-m-gallery-container            cc-m-gallery-slider                                  ">
      <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;">
        <div class="bx-viewport" aria-live="polite" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 583px;">
                <ul style="width: 9215%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(-560px, 0px, 0px);">

                        <li aria-hidden="true" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 558px; margin-right: 2px;" class="bx-clone" >
                              <img src="https://image/path/cms/image.png" data-orig-width="650" data-orig-height="680" alt="" style="height: 583.247px;">
                        </li>

                        <li aria-hidden="false" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 558px; margin-right: 2px;" >
                          <a href="/products/"><img src="https://image/path/cms/image.png" data-orig-width="650" data-orig-height="680" alt="thatBrand is super" style="height: 583.247px;"><div class="bx-caption" style="width: 533.516px; margin-left: 12px;"><span>thatBrand is super</span></div></a> 
                        </li>

                        <li aria-hidden="true" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 558px; margin-right: 2px;">
                          <a href="/products/">    <img src="https://image/path/cms/image.png" data-orig-width="650" data-orig-height="680" alt="another brand image" style="height: 583.247px;"><div class="bx-caption"><span>another brand image</span></div> </a> 
                        </li>


                        <li aria-hidden="true" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 558px; margin-right: 2px;">
                          <img src="https://image/path/cms/image.png" data-orig-width="650" data-orig-height="680" alt="" style="height: 583.247px;">
                        </li>

                </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried something like this but didn't work... Any ideas??

```
    $('.cc-m-gallery-slider ul li:has(img[alt*="thatBrand"])').addClass('thatBrand-image');


         if ( $('li .thatBrand-image').is('[aria-hidden="false"]') ) {
            $('.landing-section').hasClass("brandName");
            $('.landing-section').addClass("brandName");
        } else {
           $('.landing-section').removeClass("brandName");
        }
```

Comment: Your question and your code are somewhat difficult to understand.

From what I gather, your end goal is to add `::before` pseudo element text to a `div.landing-section`, but only if the child `li` element contains `aria-hidden=false`. Do I have that right?

Comment: @Josh, that's correct, yes! Sorry for the mess of my question and code, however I was trying to be as detailed as possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some syntax errors, and the `if` statement is entirely unnecessary.

This snippet should be sufficient to add a CSS class to the `div.landing-section` based on the `aria-hidden` values of the child `li` elements:

```
  $(".bx-viewport li[aria-hidden='false']").parents("div.landing-section").addClass("brandName");
```

And the following should remove the class if no child `li` elements have `aria-hidden=false`:

```
  $("div.landing-section:not(:has(.bx-viewport li[aria-hidden='false']))").removeClass("brandName");
```

You can see it in action on the [codepen](https://codepen.io/joshschroder/pen/PggBKR). I simplified your HTML to make it more readable.

If you're learning jQuery, it's helpful to think of the syntax being:

```
$("find-something").do_Something();
```

The [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) is also very helpful as a reference. I'd recommend giving it a look.

Comment: @CyrilConstantine -- If this was helpful, will you please mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Cyril Constantine

Here is some solution i have tried it may helps you try this

HTML:

```
    <div class="landing-section">

    <div class="right-side">
        <div class="cc-m-gallery-slider">

          <ul class="bxslider">
            <li>
              <a href="/products/"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/products/">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="thatBrand is super">
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/products/">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="another brand image">
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: true,
      slideWidth: 600,
      onSlideAfter:function(){
        $('.bxslider [aria-hidden="false"]').addClass('brandName');
        $('.bxslider [aria-hidden="true"]').removeClass('brandName');
      },
      onSliderLoad:function(){
        $('.bxslider [aria-hidden="false"]').addClass('brandName');
        $('.bxslider [aria-hidden="true"]').removeClass('brandName');
      }
    });

});
```